# Do something when a certain section id of scrolling has reached?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am searching for solution. I want to do something when the page reach a section of the one page template.

Example:
When reach the section with an id of `#about` change one-off the css of the element `#about.

Thanks in advance.
Casper

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can use http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ which should do exactly what you want.